# webclient.downloadstring returns timeout on .net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, timeout, webclient, downloadstring

I have a program that read xml from different URLs.
One of them is not working on .net framework 3.5 but the same code is working well on .net framework 4 and also on any browser. 
What could possible be the reason and how do I fix it without converting my whole project?

```
var url = "someURL";
var wcXml = new WebClient();
wcXml.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
wcXml.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
wcXml.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml;charset=UTF-8");
var srcXml = wcXml.DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: Thanks. It returns timeout: "The operation has timed out"

Comment: Right, it was in the title... Sorry for asking.